# Intermitent SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using Android Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, xiaomi, miui, https, redmi-note-10-pro

When browsing the internet using the Wi-Fi hotspot of my Android phone (**Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro**), some requests fail with the following error: `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting in Chrome for Mac OS:
[image]

I noticed that it is happening only on specific websites (I have no issues on Stack Overflow for example). This also seems to be happening regardless of the LTE network quality.

I tried using the Wi-Fi hotspot from another phone, and everything is working as intended.

I'm using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro running MIUI 12.5.6, and I'm browsing on Chrome on Mac OS 10.14.6.

Anybody have an idea on how to debug this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue, turns out the default APN was not correctly configured.

I re-configured my APN with the configuration given by my phone provider (for Orange in France, the config is here: https://assistance.orange.fr/mobile-tablette/tous-les-mobiles-et-tablettes/installer-et-utiliser/se-connecter-et-parametrer-un-reseau/se-connecter-a-un-reseau-mobile-3-4g/comment-ajouter-un-point-d-acces-internet-apn-sur-votre-mobile-xiaomi-sous-android-_321636-856633)